# includesvg only displays graph axes and not data

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, graphs, includegraphics, svg

I have two similar graphs that I'm trying to display using \includesvg on Overleaf. One renders perfectly, the other renders the axes but none of the data. An example project is linked [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xrswhdpdzbxp#8681d3).

The svg image is also rendered perfectly if opened directly with Google Chrome.

Can anyone help?

This is what is plotted:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your SVG files are basically just embedding a PNG, so there is nothing to process at all. You would have to create a proper SVG file in the first place.

Comment: so why do they render fine in chrome but not here if there's not a processing issue?

Comment: and why would it only affect one of the files (produced from identical code)?

Comment: Package `svg` utilize Inkscape for exporting SVG to PDF with optional LaTeX typesetting support if desired. So, if there is nothing plot, this is most likely an Inkscape issue.